# Проблемs с импортом кодом с гитхаб

Tags: python, telegram-bot

В общем у меня проект индивидуальный на тему "создание телеграмм бота". Я с гитхаба скачивала проекты, чтобы посмотреть вообще как создаются и за что отвечают функции и так далее. Проблема в том, что когда запускаю код любой с гитхаба, вылазит ошибка, мол модуль не скачен или подобные

Подобные вылазят, хотя у меня все скачено и по идее ошибок не должно возникать
`from telegram.constants import ParseMode ImportError: cannot import name 'ParseMode' from 'telegram.constants'`

Comment: Вы устанавливаете библиотеки используя `pip install -r requirements.txt` (где `requirements.txt` файл из репозитория)? (Разные проекты могут быть построены на разных версиях модулей и нужно установить именно нужные)

Comment: Да, я так устанавливаю все библиотеки

Answer (score 0):

Судя по ошибке код пытается использовать api `python-telegram-bot` версии 20 [в которой изменился метод импорта ParseMode](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Transition-guide-to-Version-20.0#telegramparsemode) проверьте что в файле `requirements.txt` устанавливается версия >= 20. Если да то попробуйте удалить python-telegram-bot и установить заново